# Correct way to tune CPU governor's parameters?

Tags: cpu, cpufreq, governor

Looking for explanation on how to change the parameters of the CPU governor on 22.04 and that they stick after a reboot.

I am talking about the governor's parameters like "sampling_rate",  "up_threshold", "sampling_down_factor" and so on.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reddit [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/zb5gnb/correct_way_to_tune_cpu_governors_parameters/) with answer. ... ...

Seems like [this](https://wiki.debian.org/CpuFrequencyScaling) is still valid, in the "With cpufrequtils" section.

Set governor with cpupower.
Tune the parameters in "/etc/sysfs.conf".
Apply them immediatly with "service sysfsutils restart".
check that settings are applied with "sudo cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/my_governor/my_setting"
Monitor behavior, rinse & repeat.

Set governor at boot by editing "/etc/default/cpufrequtils". Have not validated this one yet.